# simplejson: loading spanish characters -- utf-8

Tags: python, json, internationalization, simplejson

I'm trying to load some geographic data with Python's `simplejson`.

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
string = file("prCounties.txt","r").read().decode('utf-8')  
d = simplejson.loads(string)
```

The text  file has a tilde, the word should be *Añasco* instead it's `u"A\xf1asco"` which SimpleJson is not parsing.  The source is a [geoJson file from github](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/USA/PR/An%CC%83asco.geo.json)

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "properties": {"kind": "state", "state": "PR"}, "features": [[{"geometry": {"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-67.122, 18.3239], [-67.0508, 18.3075], [-67.0398, 18.291], [-67.0837, 18.2527], [-67.122, 18.2417], [-67.1603, 18.2746], [-67.1877, 18.2691], [-67.2261, 18.2965], [-67.1822, 18.3129], [-67.1275, 18.3184]]]]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"kind": "county", "name": u"A\xf1asco", "state": "PR"}}]]}
```

Python gives me the error `simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting object`

---

The script I used to load from GitHub to generate `prCounties.txt`.  The variable `counties` is a list of strings related to the locations of the relevant GEOjson data.

It's clear this is not the proper way to save this data:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
countyGeo = [ ]

for x in counties:      
    d = simplejson.loads(urllib.urlopen("https://raw.github.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/USA/PR/%s" % (x)).read())         
    countyGeo += [ d["features"][0]]
    d["features"][0]=countyGeo  
file("prCounties.txt", "w").write(str(d))
```

**EDIT**: In the last line, I replaced the `str` with `simplejson.dumps`.  I guess it encodes properly now.
    file("prCounties.txt", "w").write(simplejson.dumps(d))

Comment: `u"A\xf1asco"` is the same string as `u"Añasco"` (and `u"A\u00f1asco"` ).

Comment: The reason you're seeing it as `u"A\xf1asco"` is that (in Python 2.x), the `repr` of a unicode string escapes any non-ASCII characters. For example, at your interactive interpreter, `u'ñ'` will print out `u'\xf1'`, but `print u'ñ'` will print out `ñ`.

Comment: is there another reason the <code>simplejson</code> is not loading properly then?

Comment: Yes, because your string isn't a JSON `object`, it's a Python `repr` of a `dict`. They're often very similar, but they're not the same thing, and you can't treat them the same. In particular, you can't have `u"Añasco"` in a JSON object; you need to have a UTF-8 string literal in normal double-quotes.

Comment: Now it says: `Invalid \escape:` around `A\xf1asco`.

Comment: "Now" meaning… what? What exactly did you try, and what exactly happened?

Comment: I replaced `u"A\xf1asco"` with `"A\xf1asco"`

Comment: Well, yes, that's not a valid UTF-8 string. If you want to represent the whole thing as a UTF-8 string, you need `"A\xc3\xb1asco"` (which you can find by printing `u'Añasco'.encode('utf-8')`).

Comment: Can I just do `json.loads(file("prCounties.txt","r").read().encode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: No. First, `read` is returning you an 8-bit string; you can't encode that as UTF-8. Second, even if you had it as a `unicode`, when you encode `u'u"Añasco"'` as UTF-8, you get `'u"A\xc3\xb1asco"'`. That doesn't solve your problem. At least it prevents you from adding a new one. But again, why are you messing with encoding at all? If you have UTF-8 data, and you want to parse it as JSON, just leave it as UTF-8. Most likely, randomly throwing in encodes and decodes is what caused you to end up with non-JSON data in the first place, and shotgunning more of them in there will not help.

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I suspected: You're calling `loads` on each file, then writing the `str` of that, then trying to call `loads` on the `str`. Of course that doesn't work. If you just use `dumps` instead of `str`, you can load it back later. Or just leave the JSON strings as-is, and map names to JSON strings instead of to objects. Or… really, if you just think through what you're trying to do, it should be easy to think of something which has an obvious reverse operation, and do that something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First:

```
string = file("prCounties.txt","r").read().decode('utf-8')
```

Why are you decoding it? JSON explicitly takes UTF-8 strings. That's part of the definition of JSON. The fact that `simplejson` can handle Unicode strings makes it a little easier to use, but it effectively handles them by encoding them back to UTF-8, so… why not just leave it that way in the first place?

More importantly, where did your data come from? If `prCounties.txt` has that `u"Añasco"` in it, it's not JSON. You can't encode something to one standard and decode to a completely different standard just because they look similar.

If, for example, you did `open('prCounties.txt', 'w').write(repr(my_dict))`, you have to read it back with a Python `repr` parser (possibly `ast.literal_eval`, or maybe you have to write something yourself).

Or, alternatively, if you want to parse the data as JSON, write it as JSON in the first place.

---

According to your comment, the data was read from https://raw.github.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/USA/PR/Añasco.geo.json

The raw contents of that URL are:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","properties":{"kind":"state","state":"PR"},"features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"kind":"county","name":"Añasco","state":"PR"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-67.1220,18.3239],[-67.0508,18.3075],[-67.0398,18.2910],[-67.0837,18.2527],[-67.1220,18.2417],[-67.1603,18.2746],[-67.1877,18.2691],[-67.2261,18.2965],[-67.1822,18.3129],[-67.1275,18.3184]]]]}}
]}
```

You'll notice that there is no `"name": u"Añasco"` (or `"name": u"A\xf1asco"`, or anything similar) there. You can read this just by calling `read`—no need to decode it from UTF-8 or anything—and just pass it to `simplejson.loads` and it works just fine:

```
$ curl -O https://raw.github.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/USA/PR/Añasco.geo.json
$ cp Añasco.geo.json prCounties.txt
$ python
>>> import simplejson
>>> string = file("prCounties.txt","r").read()
>>> d = simplejson.loads(string)
>>> print d
{u'type': u'FeatureCollection', u'properties': {u'kind': u'state', u'state': u'PR'}, u'features': [{u'geometry': {u'type': u'MultiPolygon', u'coordinates': [[[[-67.122, 18.3239], [-67.0508, 18.3075], [-67.0398, 18.291], [-67.0837, 18.2527], [-67.122, 18.2417], [-67.1603, 18.2746], [-67.1877, 18.2691], [-67.2261, 18.2965], [-67.1822, 18.3129], [-67.1275, 18.3184]]]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'kind': u'county', u'name': u'A\xf1asco', u'state': u'PR'}}]}
```

See, no errors at all.

Somewhere, you've done something to this data to turn it into something else which is not JSON. My guess is that, on top of doing a bunch of unnecessary extra `decode` and `encode` calls, you've also done a `simplejson.loads`, then tried to re-`simplejson.loads` the `repr` of the `dict` you got back. Or maybe you've JSON-encoded a `dict` full of already-encoded JSON strings. Whatever you've done, that code, not the code you're showing us, is where the error is.

And the easiest fix is probably to generate `prCounties.txt` properly in the first place. It's just 70-odd downloads of a few lines apiece, and it should take maybe 2 lines of bash or 4 lines of Python to do it…

Comment: it's from `https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries/USA/PR/Añasco.geo.json` the file name and the text has a `ñ` in it.

Comment: Yes, the contents have `… "name":"Añasco",` in them. Where did you get your `… "name": u"Añasco" …` from? You've clearly done some kind of processing to the file that turns it from JSON into non-JSON. If you just parse the actual raw data in the file, it works fine.

Comment: hmm... I used `urllib.urlopen` to read it (and about 75 similar files) from Github, which I merged and saved into one file.  Then I opened that file, and this mess began.

Comment: Let's ignore the fact that `urllib.urlopen` is deprecated, because that isn't relevant here. You clearly did not just concatenate the results of calling `read` on each `urlopen` into one file, or you wouldn't have gotten this. If you no longer have the code you used to generate the `prCounties.txt` file, maybe the simplest thing is to just write new code to generate it properly?

Comment: I get: undefined name 'file', maybe I miss an import? Sorry, I'm totally new with Python

Answer (score 2):

Your input file is not valid JSON. There is a `u` before the `"A\xf1asco"` string, which is Python syntax, not JSON syntax. It should be:

```
"name":"A\xf1asco",
```

This works:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(u'{"name":"A\xf1asco"}')
{u'name': u'A\xf1asco'}
```

Comment: +1. But you don't need the external `u` either; usually you get JSON as UTF-8. For example, if you encode `{'name': u'Añasco'}` as JSON, you'll get `{"name": "A\xc3\xb1asco"}`, and that will decode to the exact same thing. (Put another way, `json.loads` is effectively calling `encode('utf-8')` on you input before decoding it.)

Comment: I suspect the json decode worked just fine but that the OP is seeing Python literals now..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The OP says he's getting "simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError". Maybe he's trying to JSON decode, and then re-JSON-decode the repr of the result or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the "u" in your prCounties.txt file (as already told). Then you can use this code, which works well to create the variable "string" in a format readable by the simplejson.loads() function:

```
import simplejson
string = file("prCounties.txt", "r").read().decode("string-escape")
string = unicode(string, "latin-1")
simplejson.loads(string)
```